# Trim Filename to be short enough

Tags: java, string, file, path

I am currently writing an API based Gui, in which I want a full Filename to appear...
The Filename is often too long, and so I want to trim this filename to leave out only as few folders as needed.
Example:

> C:\Users\RoiEX\someFolder\SomeOtherFolder\someFile.someExtension

should be trimmed to something like

> C:\...\someOtherFolder\someFile.someExtension

I have my variable fileName, which is generated by calling `file.getAbsolutePath()`.
I have a method, let's call it is `tooLarge(fileName)`
I would start like this :

```
String fileName = file.getAbsolutePath();
while(tooLarge(fileName)){
    fileName = trimPath(fileName);
}
render(fileName);
```

What should I do inside `trimPath()` ?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: WHen do you want to trim the fileName?. What are the conditions ?

Comment: @TheLostMind the code above is supposed to get called when rendered

Comment: I see. So, you already know that the length is more and have decided to trim it.

Comment: This question seems odd... How is someone else supposed to know your directory structure and where your file should be found? No one can write a method for you without knowing what your conditions and specifications are. You should come up with some specific criteria before asking or this question is at risk of being closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper regex with `replaceAll()` will work for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "C:\\asas\\Users\\RoiEX\\someFolder\\SomeOtherFolder\\someFile.someExtension";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(\\w+:\\\\).*?(\\\\\\w+\\\\\\w+.\\w+)$", "$1...$2"));  
}
```

O/P :

```
C:\...\SomeOtherFolder\someFile.someExtension
```

The above regex selects the last starting directory and last directory with file name.

Comment: Any other regex for UNIX file systems?

Comment: @RoiEX - Is it not working properly?

Comment: Haven tested it on a UNIX system, but UNIX file systems work like `/home/user/RoiEX`

Comment: Ya. And we should also allow spaces in folder / file names.. hold on @RoiEX

Comment: e.g. there is no C: or similar and there are slashes instead of backslashes - provided by `File.seperatorChar`

Comment: @RoiEX - I know :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118538/discussion-between-thelostmind-and-roiex).

Comment: @RoiEX - OK `replaceAll("(/\\w+).*?(/\\w+/\\w+.\\w+)$","$1...$2")` is the regex for UNIX. I think you should use an if else condition and 2 seperate regexes for windows and linux family. linux family paths start with `/` so you can check for that

Answer (score 1):

If you know your PATH to that directory and you are converting to a relative path, this is what you can do.

```
final String PATH = "C:\\Users\\RoiEX\\someFolder";
String path = filename.replaceFirst(PATH, "C\\..\\");
```

Comment: I would like to have this platform independent

Comment: Also the PATH might vary depending on the OS

Comment: Irrespective of the platform, Let the first and last dir be there and replace the path that you feel will be fixed with a ..(dot,dot). In this case if you know RoiEX\\someFolder is a fixed path just replace this with a dot,dot.